# Build a string json_encode

Tags: php, json

I am working with a php file. I want to present 8 css buttons.

```
   echo "<div class='num_outer'>right ";

   <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code()">"1"</button>
   <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code()">"2"</button>
   <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code()">"3"</button>
   <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code()">"4"</button>

   echo $colors;
   echo " </div>";// end num_outer
```

Okay so I want them to choose one or more colors and have them concatenate into the variable $colors. 
So $colors would look like "142", if 3 where chosen. 
After hours of researching, it appears json_encode may be the best. But I am open to any suggestions.

I also want it to work on all browsers. 
Thank you for your help.

edit ------------------------------------------ Suggested code -----------

```
  echo "<div class='num_outer'>right ";
  echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
  echo "var str = ''; \n";
  echo " function do_some_code(val)";
  echo "{";
echo "   str+=val;";
echo "}";
  echo "</script> ";
  echo " <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('1')">"1"</button>";
  echo " <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('2')">"2"</button>";
  echo "  <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('3')">"3"</button>";
  echo "  <button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('4')">"4"</button>";

  echo "   <button type="num-btn" onclick="window.location.href='get_tst1a.php?        str='+str">Show me value</button>";
   $str = $_GET['str']; 
   echo " </div>";// end num_outer
```

---

My file name for this is get_tst1a.php

Comment: You cannot mix JavaScript and PHP that way. PHP runs on the server, JavaScript in the browser. Or I don't understand your question...

Comment: It sounds like you want check boxes, not buttons.

Comment: Well I want the click on the button to be the action. I don't want a submit button. Thats why I though json-encode .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using echo for all html tags.
Your php string concatination is breaking.
Try below.

```
<div class='num_outer'>right 
<script language="JavaScript">
var str = ''; 
function do_some_code(val)
{str+=val;}
</script>
<button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('1')">"1"</button>
<button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('2')">"2"</button>
<button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('3')">"3"</button>
<button type="num-btn" onclick="do_some_code('4')">"4"</button>
<button type="num-btn" onclick="window.location.href='get_tst1a.php?str='+str">Show me value</button>"
<? 
    echo $str = $_GET['str']; 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I want to store the string. How do I get it from "alert(str);" to php to store?

Comment: What do you want to do in php side? I think you need form. Do you aware of form?

Comment: I am aware of form. But I want a click on each button, and then store the string.

Comment: No, I posted the changes above. Looks like many problems to me.